# Awk to filter content of a file using the line number of another file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I am trying to use `awk` to filter some content from a file based on the content of another file. But it is not working.

I got two files,  orig_data and noghest_data. Both files have same number of lines and lines correspond to same events but different content. I want to print the contents of noghest_data corresponding to lines where the orig_data does not start with the `Ghest`.  My below code is not working. It prints everything.

```
awk -F " "  'NR==FNR{if($0 ~ /^Ghest/) {line[NR]++} next} !(NR in line) {print $0}' orig_data.txt noghest_data.txt
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show example input files, the expected output and your actual output. I think the condition `!(NR in line)` should be `!(FNR in line)`.

Comment: @Bodo. Yes that is correct. You can add that as answer.  I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Please show example input and expected output.

Comment: This site is intended not only to answer the question for you personally, but also as a help for others that may have similar questions. Adding small example input files (both a few matching and non-matching lines) and the corresponding expected output would really improve the question for this purpose.

Comment: The `++` in `line[NR]++` is doing nothing but use up memory and CPU cycles, `line[NR]` is all you need there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is almost fine. Slightly simplified:

```
awk 'NR == FNR && /^Ghest/ {line[NR]} NR > FNR && ! (FNR in line)' \
  orig_data.txt noghest_data.txt
```

The first pattern (`NR == FNR && /^Ghest/`) only evaluates to true for lines of the first input file that also start with the string `Ghest`. The corresponding action adds the current line number as an index of the `line` array.

The second pattern (`NR > FNR && ! (FNR in line)`) evaluates to true for input files other than the first one, *if* the line number relative to the current file is not an index of the `line` array (`print $0` is the default action when the action is omitted).

As [Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton) [suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609341/awk-to-filter-content-of-a-file-using-the-line-number-of-another-file/609352?noredirect=1#comment1137366_609352), this can also be made more efficient by only comparing `NR` to `FNR` once:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { if (/^Ghest/) line[NR]; next } !(FNR in line)'
```

Comment: Use `awk 'NR == FNR { if (/^Ghest/) line[NR]; next } !(FNR in line)'` so you don't compare NR with FNR twice.